# Checking the file size in an -IF and using it in the action using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, size

I have users that have a file in a dynamic location.

What I'm trying to do now is to check if the file size is greater than x

I have done research and have this code:

```
$foreach ($user in $users)
{
    $file = Get-Item $path

          if($file.Length -gt 40 )
          {
                 $file.Length / 1Gb "is too big!" 
          }
}
```

I tried playing around with the 1/Gb (using it in the line of output and also in the `if` without result . It keeps giving me the result in kilobytes.

I tried:

```
$foreach ($user in $users)
    {
        $file = Get-Item $path

              if($file.Length -gt 40 /1Gb )
              {
                     $file.Length / 1Gb "is too big!" 
              }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What size are you trying to check for? Files will always be bigger than `40/1GB`, because that answer is less than 0.

Comment: I want to check if the size of the file is greater than 40 GB, if it is, it needs to display the size (in GB). But now it doesn't check it indeed and just shows the file size in KB

Comment: So just ask if `$file.Length -gt 40GB`. To output your string, write `"{0} is too big!" -f ($file.Length / 1GB)`.

Comment: doesn't work Bill

Comment: You must not be writing something correctly, then. It works fine for me here.

Comment: Thanks Bill, ill recheck your answer to be sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to divide `$file.Length` by 1GB. Rather than dividing 40 by 1GB.

```
foreach ($user in $users){
    $file = Get-Item $path
    $SizeinGB = $file.Length / 1GB
    if($SizeinGB -gt 40) {
        "$SizeinGB GB is too big!" 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much